# How to get ID from another file in php?

Tags: php, edit, show

I'm going to make edit menu in my web. so I direct the page from product into edit page. What I'm confused is how to get the productID from product's page to use in edit page?
Here is my code in product

```
<?php $query= "SELECT * FROM game";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>
<div class="gameBox">
    <div style="margin:5px;">
        <?php echo "<image src=\"images/".$data['gameId'].".png\" alt=\"gameImage\" </image>"?>
        <div class="cleaner"></div>
        <div class="myLabel">Name</div><div>: <?php echo $data['gameName'];?></div>
        <div class="myLabel">Developer</div><div>: <?php echo $data['gameDeveloper']; ?></div>
        <div class="myLabel">Price</div><div>: $ <?php echo $data['gamePrice']; ?></div>
        <br />
        <a href="edit.php" <?php $id=$data['gameId'];?>><input type="button" value="Edit"/></a>
        <a href="<!-- Delete -->"><input type="button" value="Delete"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

and it's my code in edit page

```
<?php include("connect.php");
$id[0] = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE gameId=".$id."";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>
    <form action="doUpdate.php" method="post">
        <?php echo "<image src=\"images/".$id.".png\" alt=\"gameImage\" </image>"?>
        <div class="cleaner"></div>
        <div class="myLabel">Name</div><div>: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['gameName'];?>" id="gameName" name="gameName"/></div>
        <div class="myLabel">Developer</div><div>: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['gameDeveloper'];?>" id="gameDeveloper" name="gameDeveloper"/></div>
        <div class="myLabel">Price</div><div>: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['gamePrice'];?>" id="gamePrice" name="gamePrice"/></div>
        <br/>
        <div id="txtError">
        <!--error message here-->
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <a href="product.php"><input type="button" value="Cancel"/></span></a>
<?php } ?>
```

When I try to access edit page, there's an error it said

```
"Undefined index:$id[0] = $_REQUEST['id'];"
```

in edit page.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.  At a minimum, call `intval()` to cast the string $id as an integer:  `$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);`

Comment: @Michael: I typically do something like `$id = (int)$_GET[...]` -- any idea whether one is better?  The same?

Comment: @jedwards They're basically equivalent.  `intval()` as a radix option if needed. Really, it is best to check that the thing is an integer as expected, and if not, then don't do any work against the database at all.

Comment: @jedwards Lots of PHP coders will just accept the values received by the script without checking types and bounds, but that is terrible practice.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458888/how-to-update-database-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing two methods of passing data between pages, forms and query strings in `<a href...>`s.

**Forms**:

Data is in `<input>`-type elements (or friends) and inside a `<form...>` tag.

For example

```
<form action="handler.php">
    <input type="text" name="var1" />
    <input type="text" name="var2" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Usually passed via POST and accessed in PHP via `$_POST`.

For example, the values in the text boxes referenced above would be accessed with something like:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['var1'];  // First text box
echo $_POST['var2'];  // Second text box
```

**Links**:

Passed as query strings in `<a href...>`, for example:

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?var1=foo&var2=bar">Click Me</a>
```

Usually passed via GET and accessed in PHP via `$_GET`.

For example, the values in the query string provided above would be accessed with something like

```
<?php
echo $_GET['var1'];  // "foo"
echo $_GET['var2'];  // "bar"
```

---

So in this case it looks like you're hyperlinking an input button -- which is not the usual way to do things, but you would fix it by changing this:

```
<a href="edit.php" <?php $id=$data['gameId'];?>><input type="button" value="Edit"/></a>
```

To, this

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $data['gameId'];?>"><input type="button" value="Edit"/></a>
```

And then reference the variable in edit.php as `$_GET['id']`.

But since you know it's going to be an integer and nothing else, something like:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Is good enough sanitation (at least for that variable).

Lastly, I notice you assign a variable to `$id[0]` but then reference `$id`.  Assigning a variable to `$id[0]` is not the same as assigning it to `$id`, as `$id` is an array in the former and an integer in the latter.  It seems to me that you can just drop the `[0]` w.r.t. `$id` in your edit.php

Comment: I used $id = $_REQUEST['id']; not include the array and it works too :). thanks dude

Comment: No problem but please read my point about sanitizing the variable in the second to last paragraph or @Michael's in his comment.

Comment: Why in edit still error, although I used $id= (int)$_GET['id']; in edit.php? It said Undefined index

Comment: It seems like that means that your query string is a bit off -- can you paste the full url of the edit.php page you're sent to?  (You can strip the domain name, I just need everything after and including `edit.php`)

Comment: Also, you might consider `$id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];` if `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add the id as a parameter to your edit url:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $data['gameId'];?>"><input type="button" value="Edit"/></a>
```

also at the top of your edit.php:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque [Yes it will](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), though it is still recommended to use `$_GET` explicitly..

Comment: I think the assignment inside the `<?php ... ?>` tag is a typo.

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque $_REQUEST is used both for POST and GET :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass through the query string

```
<a href="edit.php?<?php $id=$data['gameId'];?>>
```

In this case your PHP code will get change to

```
$id[0] = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: You mean `$_GET`, there is no `$_QUERYSTRING`.