# How to update database in php?

Tags: php, database

I wanna update my product when there's user login. Here's my code in edit.php

```
                <?php
                $id= (int)$_GET['id'];

                $query = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE gameId=".$id."";
                $rs = mysql_query($query);
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                {
            ?>
            <form action="doUpdate.php" method="post">
                <?php echo "<image src=\"images/".$id.".png\" alt=\"gameImage\" </image>"?>

                <div class="cleaner"></div>

                <div class="myLabel">Name</div><div>: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['gameName'];?>" name="gameName"/></div>
                <div class="myLabel">Developer</div><div>: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['gameDeveloper'];?>" name="gameDeveloper"/></div>
                <div class="myLabel">Price</div><div>: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['gamePrice'];?>" name="gamePrice"/></div>

                <br/>

                <div id="txtError" style="color:#D70005">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($err))
                        {
                            if($err==1) echo"All Fields must be filled";
                            else if($err==2) echo"Price must be numeric";
                            else if($err==3) echo"Price must be between 1-10";
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                <a href="product.php"><input type="button" value="Cancel"/></span></a>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </form>
```

This is my code in doUpdate.php

```
<?php
$nama = $_POST['gameName'];
$dev = $_POST['gameDeveloper'];
$harga =$_POST['gamePrice'];
$id= (int)$_REQUEST['id'];

if($nama == "" || $dev == "" || $harga == "" )
{
    header("location:edit.php?err=1");  
}
else if(!is_numeric($harga))
{
    header("location:edit.php?err=2");  
}
else if($harga < 1 || $harga >10)
{
    header("location:edit.php?err=3");  
}
else
{
    $query = "UPDATE game SET gameName='".$nama."', gameDeveloper='".$dev."', gamePrice=".$harga." where gameId=".$id.""; 
    mysql_query($query);
    header("location:product.php");
}
```

?>

Why I can't change name, developer, or price even I already give the action in form? And why if I delete the name, developer, and price to know wether the validation works or not, it said that Undefined index in edit.php $id= (int)$_GET['id']; ?

Comment: Before you go any furher with this code. you need to read up about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and handling [SQL errors](http://php.net/mysql_error)

Comment: When you say you can't change the details, what do you mean? What happens when you try? Do you get an error message, or does the form submit but the database not update?

Comment: There's no error message, I could submit but the database not update.

Comment: @MarcB I have read, but I still got confuse with it

Comment: @greenthunder: then stop developing until you do. If you can't understand how to implement basic security precautions in PHP code, you shouldn't be writing PHP, especially as it looks like you're developing a game for public use. Stick that out onto the web and your site and your server are going to get destroyed.

Comment: @MarcB FYI, I used localhost as server. Cause I'm still learning it, not real developing

Comment: @greenthunder: doesn't matter. Learning secure PHP programming practices now, otherwise you'll have a lot of unlearning to do later.

Comment: @greenthunder  http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html please read this use php PDO it will help you to prevent those security issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `$_REQUEST['id']` in doUpdate.php but there is no such field in the form.
You have to add it as a hidden field.

Also you have to format your strings.
Every string you're gonna put into query you have to escape special characters in.